# Cronjob not working properly when run as scheduled

Tags: linux, permissions, shell, shell-script, cron

This file is placed in `/etc/cron.weekly/` :

```
#!/bin/sh

# For syncing some files with OneDrive
# Assumes that the sync target is set up as OneDrive:Syncs in rclone

if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
    exec sudo -H -u <user> $0 "$@"
fi

notify() {
    #Detect the name of the display in use
    local display=":$(ls /tmp/.X11-unix/* | sed 's#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##' | head -n 1)"

    #Detect the user using such display
    local user=$(who | grep '('$display')' | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1)

    #Detect the id of the user
    local uid=$(id -u $user)

    sudo -u $user DISPLAY=$display DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$uid/bus notify-send -a rclone -h string:desktop-entry:alacritty "$@"
}

notify "OneDrive sync" "Sync started..."
flock -n .onedrivesynclock rclone sync -c -L --log-file=logfile --log-level INFO source OneDrive:Syncs
notify "OneDrive sync" "Sync finished!"
```

Obviously, the `logfile`, `source`, `<user>` etc. are replaced with proper values. This script works when checked using `run-parts` but fails when ir runs automatically as scheduled. The notifications work, but not the sync. I can't find any logs anywhere either. My guess is it's some kind of a permissions issue, but I don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: Did you check `syslog` for entries with `CRON`? Any errors there?

Comment: I cannot find the `syslog` files, but there's nothing in `journalctl`.